# How to get content from Liferay structure

Tags: liferay

I need help getting JournalArticle content of a particular content structure in liferay.

I want to display the field values of the Journal content. This content has a custom structure.

Comment: You can get all articles by structure using `JournalArticleLocalServiceUtil.getStructureArticles` with the help of `groupId` and `ddmStructureKey`.

Comment: What i really wanted was to extracting content from the Journal Article as this article has a custom structure

Comment: i will post my answer below as i have found a way around that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The structure is essentially an xml structure of the type DYNAMIC ELEMENT tags.
The value of the different fields of the structure that defines the article can be extracted using the format

```
Document document = SaxReaderUtil.read(journalarticle.getContent());

Node fieldNode = document.selectSingleNode("/root/dynamic-element[@name='Field-Name']/dynamic-content"); 

String brand = brandNode.getText();
```

`

See more at http://liferayiseasy.blogspot.com.ng/2015/08/get-web-contentjournal-article-fields.html

Answer (score 0):

We have **Structure + WebContent**. The fields are stored in the 'JournalArticle' table > 'Content' field as an xml so we must parse it with SAXReaderUtil to get the fields and their values.

```
long companyId = getCompanyId();
long groupId = getGroupId(companyId, GroupConstants.GUEST);

JournalArticle article = JournalArticleLocalServiceUtil.getArticleByUrlTitle(groupId, "33736");
SAXReaderUtil sax = new SAXReaderUtil();
Document doc = sax.read(article.getContent());
Node rootEle = doc.getRootElement();
Node telephoneNode = rootEle.selectSingleNode("/root/dynamic-element[@name='Telephone']/dynamic-content");
String telephone = telephoneNode.getText();
```

And we add resources...

```
public static long getCompanyId() {
    return (CompanyThreadLocal.getCompanyId() != 0) ? CompanyThreadLocal.getCompanyId() : PortalUtil.getDefaultCompanyId();
}

public long getGroupId(long companyId, String groupName) {
    long groupId = 0;
    try {
        groupId = GroupLocalServiceUtil.getGroup(companyId, groupName).getGroupId();
    } catch (PortalException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return groupId;
}
```